# React Testing Library multiple async fetch request within useEffect() failing to render data

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am writing tests using React Testing library and I am trying to assert that the results of a fetch request persist to the DOM. The issue comes when I try to run two async functions within the same useEffect function, I believe a race condition is causing the page to render in a way I'm not expecting and I cannot seem to understand how to resolve this.

As a user, I want to click a button on the page. That button will set a parameter. That parameter can and will trigger an async fetch call which will trigger a dom update, and then after another fetch call will be made and also trigger a dom update.

I tried putting together a codesandbox to help answers out but the tests don't run right correctly because of a long standing known codesandbox error "jest.mock is not a function". Regardless, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-qx3z25?file=/src/Fake/Fake.js

I'm really struggling here, any input would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Here is a generalization of the actual component files in question:

/Fake/Fake.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getRequest } from "./requests";

let payload = { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" };

const Fake = () => {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState();
  const [data2, setData2] = useState();
  const [someText, setSomeText] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    const async1 = async () => {
      const newData1 = await getRequest(payload);
      console.log(newData1);
      if (!didCancel) {
        setLoading(false);
        setData1(newData1);
      }
    };
    const async2 = async () => {
      payload = { a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" };
      const newData2 = await getRequest(payload);
      console.log(newData2);
      if (!didCancel) {
        setData2(newData2);
      }
    };
    async1();
    async2();
    return () => (didCancel = true);
  }, [someText]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setSomeText("the button was clicked"); // just change the state to someText the useEffect()
  };

  return (
    <div data-testid="fake__wrapper">
      <button data-testid="fake__button" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        Push the button
      </button>
      {loading && <div data-testid="fake__loader">Loading...</div>}
      {!loading && data1 && (
        <p data-testid="fake__data--1">{`Data 1 acquired ${data1.d} ${data1.e} ${data1.f}`}</p>
      )}
      {!loading && data2 && (
        <p data-testid="fake__data--2">{`Data 2 acquired ${data2.d} ${data2.e} ${data2.f}`}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fake;
```

/Fake/requests.js

```
export const getRequest = async (payload) =>
  await fetch("/fake/request", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => {
      return err.message;
    });
```

/Fake/tests/Fake.test.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import {
  render,
  screen,
  act,
  waitForElementToBeRemoved,
  fireEvent,
} from "@testing-library/react";
import Fake from "../Fake";

let loaderNode, buttonNode, data1Node, data2Node;

const mockData = { d: "d", e: "e", f: "f" };
const mockGetRequest = Promise.resolve(mockData);
jest.mock("../requests", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("../requests");
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    getRequest: () => mockGetRequest,
  };
});

const pulseCheck = () => {
  expect(screen.getByTestId("fake__wrapper")).toMatchScreenshot();
};

const loadingCompleteAssertion = async () => {
  // first loading node appears
  loaderNode = screen.getByTestId("fake__loader");
  expect(loaderNode).toBeInTheDocument();

  // wait for useEffect's async1 to fetch data1
  await act(() => mockGetRequest);
  // then wait for loadingNode to be removed
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByTestId("fake__loader"));

  // expect only data1 node, not data2
  data1Node = await screen.findByTestId("fake__data--1");
  expect(data1Node).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(data1Node.innerHTML).toBe(
    `Data 1 acquired ${mockData.d} ${mockData.e} ${mockData.f}`
  );
  pulseCheck();
  data2Node = await screen.findByTestId("fake__data--2");
  expect(data2Node).not.toBeInTheDocument();

  // wait for useEffect's async2 to fetch data2
  await act(() => mockGetRequest);

  // expect data2 node
  data2Node = await screen.findByTestId("fake__data--2");
  expect(data2Node).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(data2Node.innerHTML).toBe(
    `Data 2 acquired ${mockData.d} ${mockData.e} ${mockData.f}`
  );
};

describe("Fund Performance React component", () => {
  it("should fetch on button press", async () => {
    render(<Fake />);

    loadingCompleteAssertion();

    buttonNode = screen.getByTestId("fake__button");
    fireEvent.click(buttonNode);

    loadingCompleteAssertion();
  });
});
```

/Fake/tests/Fake.tests.jsx.snap

```
exports[`Fund Performance React component should fetch on button press 1`] = `
<div
  data-testid="fake__wrapper"
>
  <button
    data-testid="fake__button"
  >
    Push the button
  </button>
  <p
    data-testid="fake__data--1"
  >
    Data 1 acquired d e f
  </p>
  <p
    data-testid="fake__data--2"
  >
    Data 2 acquired d e f
  </p>
</div>
`;
```

log

```
 FAIL  Fake/tests/Fake.test.jsx
  Fake component
    ✕ should fetch on button press (43 ms)

  ● Fake component › should fetch on button press

    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    expected document not to contain element, found <p data-testid="fake__data--2">Data 2 acquired d e f</p> instead

      46 |   pulseCheck();
      47 |   data2Node = await screen.findByTestId("fake__data--2");
    > 48 |   expect(data2Node).not.toBeInTheDocument();
         |                         ^
      49 |
      50 |   // wait for useEffect's async2 to fetch data2
      51 |   await act(() => mockGetRequest);

      at toBeInTheDocument (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:48:25)
      at call (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:2:1)
      at Generator.tryCatch (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:2:1)
      at Generator._invoke [as next] (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:2:1)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:2:1)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (src/components/React/FundPerformance/tests/Fake.test.jsx:2:1)
```

I was expecting the loading node to be removed, the data 1 node to display but not the data 2 node, then after another fetch request data 2 node will display